# Two Unrelated Conditions - Expected Command Error

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to get the turtle breed foragers to reduce the food source by a small amount and become green if there is a leader, but to become orange and reduce the food by 1 unit if not, which allows the first turtle to reach the food patch to become the leader.
To the best of my knowledge, the two conditions linked by and should work, but for some reason I get an "expected command" error. Could you help resolve this?

```
to look-for-food  ;; turtle procedure
  if food > 0 and not any? leaders 
  [ set color orange + 1     ;; pick up food
    set food food - 1        ;; and reduce the food source
    rt 180
      stop]
    [set color green + 1
    set food food - .5
    rt 180
      stop]
end
```

Also, how do I incorporate food quality and chemical, which was originally an if procedure that was part of look-for-food? Or do I need to write a new procedure for that?

```
if (chemical >= 0.05) and (chemical < 2)
  [ uphill-chemical ]
  if food-quality > 0
  [uphill food]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `ifelse` not `if`. The `if` tests runs the code block if the condition is true but does nothing (just skips it) if it is false.